# instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior=stop is not supported for spot instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x, amazon-ec2-spot-market

I am trying to provision spot instance using Ansible 2.8. When i run my playbook, i encountered the following error. "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior=stop is not supported for spot instances."

However, the strange thing is that in my playbook, i did not specify anything to stop the spot instances.

Does anyone have any idea what might have caused the error?

$ ansible-playbook test.yml

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note
>   that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [Create an ec2 instance] **************************************************
>   TASK [Create an ec2 instance] **************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior=stop is not supported for spot instances."}
>   PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
>   localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Below is a portion of the yaml file that I executed.

```
tasks:
  - name: Create an ec2 instance
      ec2:
        spot_price: '0.24'
        spot_wait_timeout: 600
        aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        keypair: "{{ keypair }}"
        group_id: "{{ group_id}}"
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ ami }}"
        wait: yes
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        spot_launch_group: report_generators
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/ec2_module.html#parameters), `instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior` defaults to `stop`, which is why you must override it with `instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior: terminate` in your case

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It fixes the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the sample code in the manual page are misleading.